# TF-Lite: PReLU works incorrectly after converting pb model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow2.0

In the pb model, I have a `PRelu` layer. Because `tflite` do not have `PRelu` OP, so I convert the `PRelu` to `Relu` like this:

```python
 pos = relu(x)
 neg = - alphas * relu(-x)
 return pos + neg
```

When converting to `tflite` model, the `PRelu` will be replaced by `relu` and negative OPs. But when converting, the neg part `relu` op between two negative op is dropped by `toco`. The converted model looked like this:

```python
pos = relu(x)
neg = -alphas * (-x)
return pos + neg
```

any problem?

Comment: Hi @xhsoldier. This issue is solved by the newest tflite. Btw, how did you deal with the variable input size of pnet? Thanks

Comment: @HoaVu, To simply resolve this problem, change the PRelu to Max(x, 0) + alphas* Min(0, x)

Comment: I meant another issue. TFLite requires fixed concrete input size while pnet works with many scaled version of the input image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow Lite fuses the activation function with the op itself, so `Relu` ops will be removed from the graph. Quote from [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md) (that also mentions about `tf.nn.relu`):

> Note that many of those operations don't have TensorFlow Lite equivalents and the corresponding model will not be convertible if they can't be elided or fused.

---

Let's see what it means. Your above code of PReLU in TensorFlow, visualized using [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard), looks like following (the **ORIGINAL** graph):

```
conv --> relu ---------------------\
     \-> neg -> relu -> mul -> neg --> add
```

However, due to the fact that TfLite fuses the `Relu` ops with the previous op (more in [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md)), it will **TRY** to make something like this (note that `[A+B]` is a fused layer of `A` and `B` ops):

```
[conv+relu] -----------------------------\
            \-> [neg+relu] -> mul -> neg --> add
```

But, since `neg` operation (unary minus) doesn't have activation function by design, what **ACTUALLY** happens inside TF-Lite looks like following (this was tested by myself on version `1.9.0`):

```
[conv+relu] ----------------------\
            \-> neg -> mul -> neg --> add
```

So, it makes no sense!

---

My personal work-around of this is the following (considering you already have a trained `*.pb` model and don't want to re-train a new model just because the architecture has changed):

```python
def tflite_tolerant_prelu(_x, alpha, name_scope):
    with tf.name_scope(name_scope):
        alpha = tf.constant(alpha, name='alpha')
        return tf.maximum(_x, 0) + alpha * tf.minimum(_x, 0)

def replace_prelu(graph, prelu_block_name, tensor_before, tensor_after):
    alpha = graph.get_tensor_by_name(os.path.join(prelu_block_name, 'alpha:0'))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        alpha_val = alpha.eval()
    new_prelu = tflite_tolerant_prelu(tensor_before,
            alpha_val, prelu_block_name + '_new')
    tf.contrib.graph_editor.swap_inputs(tensor_after.op, [new_prelu])

before = mtcnn_graph.get_tensor_by_name('pnet/conv1/BiasAdd:0')
after = mtcnn_graph.get_tensor_by_name('pnet/pool1:0')
replace_prelu(mtcnn_graph, 'pnet/PReLU1', before, after)
```

This code was used to transfer [MTCNN](https://github.com/AITTSMD/MTCNN-Tensorflow) from TensorFlow to TensorFlow Lite. Looks a bit ugly (definitely needs make it look cleaner), but it is fully functional and does the job.  Note that I used the graph editor tool [`tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor) to modify the graph in offline-mode.

Comment: I replace the PRelu with max min op between x and 0, also solve this problem, Which is much easier.

Comment: @xhsoldier after posting an answer, I've realized that... there's no "Abs" operation in TF-Lite. So what I'm using right now is also `min` and `max` ops.

Answer (score 1):

To simply resolve this problem, change the PRelu to 
Max(x, 0) + alphas* Min(0, x)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, use this code:

```
pos = tf.nn.relu(x)
neg = -alphas * tf.nn.relu(-x)
```

Then using **tf 2.9.1** with `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter` and set `converter.experimental_new_converter = False`

After conversion the `prelu` display correctly in **netron**.
[check tflite visualized by netron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txd7p.png)